# Linear Transformations and Continuity

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I've been struggling with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity with respect to linear transformations and was hoping for some clarification.

Suppose that we have $T : V \mapsto W$ is a linear transformation between normed vector spaces $V$ and $W$. Suppose we also have that $T$ is continuous at $0 \in V.$

Would the correct statement of continuity be $$\forall x \in V, \forall \epsilon, \exists \delta \ni : |x| < \delta \implies |T(x)| < \epsilon ?$$

If this is the case, wouldn't this mean that $T$ is continuous everywhere? We can shift $x$ by some element $a \in V$ and since the above statement is true for every $x \in V,$ it must also be the case that

$$\forall x, a \in V, \forall \epsilon, \exists \delta \ni : |x-a| < \delta \implies |T(x) - T(a)| < \epsilon. $$

So if $T$ (a linear transformation) is continuous at a single point (doesn't matter where), it must be continuous everywhere?

Comment: Yes, this is true and your argument is correct.

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy way to think about this geometrically/pictorially?

Comment: One "pictorial" idea here: saying that the function is continuous at $0$ means saying that the set $S = \{x : |T(x)| < \epsilon\}$ is "big enough", i.e. that it contains a ball of radius $\delta$ around $0$ for some $\delta > 0$.  The equivalent set at $a$, $\{x:|T(x) - T(a)| < \epsilon\}$, is the exact same set we had before shifted over by $a$.  That is, this new set is $S + a$.  So, if one set is "big enough", they're all big enough.